# Every time I mouse click in the <body> my function I created runs

Tags: javascript, button, addeventlistener, innerhtml

I want a new paragraph every time I click on the button I created using innerhtml

I've done the correct syntax in JavaScript. I want my paragraph to only change when I click the button I created.

```
var button = document.getElementById("createpara"); 

document.getElementById("showpara").innerHTML;

function writepara() {

    document.getElementById("showpara").innerHTML = '<p>This is IT</p>';
}

document.addEventListener("click",writepara, false);
```

I want my paragraph to only change when I click the button I created.

Comment: You're assigning the click event to the entire document.

Try button.addEventListener()

Answer (score 2):

you should make you code like this

```
button.addEventListener("click",writepara);
```

instade of

```
document.addEventListener("click",writepara);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @MohammedHendy's comment

When you bind an event listener, it's hierarchical. It will bubble up the DOM and trigger all event listeners until it reaches the top most node.

For example:

if I have this:

```
<div>
   <button>Text</button>
<div>
```

and i put an event listener on the `div` but **not** the `button`, when the button is clicked, its as if I clicked on the `div`.

If I want the event to trigger only when the button is clicked then **ONLY**  set the event listener on the `button`

in your case you've applied it to the `document` which represents the entire page. That's like saying `"If you click ANYWHERE on this page, I want this function to run"`